# Confusing Makefile rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Just a little confused by Makefile working properly in the first example and absolutely not working in the second.

Working:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror
FILES=$(addprefix src/, ft_putnbr ft_putchar main)
OBJ=$(addsuffix .o, $(FILES))
NAME=put

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(NAME) $(OBJ)
%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $^ -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -I includes/
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)
```

Not working:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror
FILES=$(addprefix obj/, ft_putnbr ft_putchar main)
OBJ=$(addsuffix .o, $(FILES))
NAME=put

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(NAME) $(OBJ)
%.o: $(subst obj,src, %.c)
    gcc -c $^ -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -I includes/
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)
```

The only difference being the FILES prefix set to obj/ because i wanted to separate obj files from source files and so i needed to use $(substitute) function to change the directory in one of the rules. 
The second Makefile produces:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/ft_putnbr.o', needed by 'put'.  Stop.
```

Does anyone see my mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a makefile, the contexts that are subject to expansion are of the form
`$(...)` or `${...}`

A pattern rule is not one of those. So:

```
%.o: %.c
    ...
```

is interpreted by `make` as meaning that `stem.o` is made from a `stem.c`
by doing `...`, for any value of `stem`, but `%.o: %.c` is not of the form `$(...)` and it is
not expanded.

Hence, in the context,

```
%.o: $(subst obj,src, %.c)
```

the meaning of:

```
$(subst obj,src, %.c)
```

is simply: *the result of replacing all occurrences of* `obj` *with* `src` *in the string* `%.c`.
There are no occurrences of `obj` in the string `%.c`. So that result is simply `%.c`,
unchanged. So your second makefile is equivalent to:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror
FILES=$(addprefix obj/, ft_putnbr ft_putchar main)
OBJ=$(addsuffix .o, $(FILES))
NAME=put

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(NAME) $(OBJ)
%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $^ -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -I includes/
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)
```

in which, for example, the target `obj/ft_putnbr.o` will satisfy the
rule `%.o: %.c` if and only if there exists a prerequisite `obj/ft_putnbr.c`.
And it doesn't exist. Hence:

```
No rule to make target 'obj/ft_putnbr.o
```

Instead use:

**Makefile**

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror
SRCS=ft_putnbr.c ft_putchar.c main.c
OBJS=$(addprefix obj/,$(SRCS:.c=.o))
NAME=put

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)

obj/%.o: src/%.c | obj
    gcc -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -I includes/

obj:
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    rm -fr obj $(NAME)
```

or similar. This makefile, incidentally, ensures that the directory `obj` exists
before attempting to compile any object files into it, by making that directory an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)
of `$(OBJS)`.